# How to Show Create Procedure by another User?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can get a list of procedures by executing the following:

```
show procedure status where Db='test1';
```

And normally, we can get the `CREATE` syntax by executing the following:

```
show create procedure sampleProcedure1;
```

But the `CREATE Procedure` shows empty. Is there any workaround to get the original `CREATE` of the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html):

> To use either statement, you must be the user named in the routine `DEFINER` clause or have `SELECT` access to the `mysql.proc` table. If you do not have privileges for the routine itself, the value displayed for the `Create Procedure` or `Create Function` field will be `NULL`.

So the solution is to give the user `SELECT` access to `mysql.proc`:

```
GRANT SELECT on mysql.proc TO 'user'@'hostname'
```

Replace `user` and `hostname` with the appropriate values.